# Multilevel moderated mediation with continuous variables

Tags: r

I am a beginner in `R`, so please forgive me if my question reflects insufficient background.

I am trying to run a moderated mediation model using the `mediation` and `lme4` libraries.

All of my variables are continuous. My data have a nested structure with individuals nested in branches (Branch).

In the model I'm trying to test, my predictor/independent variable (`abranch`) is at the branch level. My mediator (`bmed`) and outcome (`cout`) are at the individual level. And the effect of the mediator is moderated by another individual level variable (`dmod`). So in my model I have `abranch` predicting `bmed`, and `bmed*dmod` are predicting `cout`.

This is the syntax I've used:

```
med.fit <- glmer(
    bmed ~ abranch + (1|Branch),
    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
    data = Dataset
)

out.fit <- glmer(
    cout ~ dmod*bmed + (1+bmed|Branch),
    family = binomial(link = "logit"),
    data = Dataset
)
```

I was then thinking of using:

```
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "abranch", mediator = "bmed",
+ sims = 100)
summary(med.out)
```

But even before getting to the last two lines, I get the following error:

```
Error in eval(family$initialize, rho) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1
```

I now realize that this is because I'm using the "binomial"/logit family whereas my DV is continuous and not between 0 and 1. What can I do, given the nature of my variables?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with predictors, but with *responses*. You can have any kind of predictor you want. What variable types are `bmed` and `cout` ?  For a binomial model, you need data of the form "x out of N" trials (where N may be == 1); if N>1 you need to specify N ...  (2) in the second model do you mean `(1+bmed|Branch)` ? or `(1|Branch)`? (I can't imagine a syntax with two `|` in the same term working ...)

Comment: 1) Ah, so is there a model I could use if I have a continuous variable, that ranges beyond 0 and 1 as my DV? and 2) yes, in the second model I copied incorrectly - I meant (1+bmed}Branch), thanks.

Comment: The default `glmer` is for a Gaussian linear model. You're overriding that default by specifying `family = binomial(link = "logit"),`. If you delete that argument entirely, you will use the default instead of the binomial model.

Comment: Oh, great. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: Tried it. I get this warning: "calling glmer() with family=gaussian (identity link) as a shortcut to lmer() is deprecated; please call lmer() directly"   Is this reason for concern?

Comment: So I replaced the glmer function with lmer, and then I got an error about the number of observation not being equivalent across the med.fit and out.fit models. So I added "dropobs=TRUE". And now I'm getting this error: "Error in `[.data.frame`(m.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected"             Any ideas??